# C++ How to convert last 4 characters of array to an integer?

Tags: c++, arrays, character, iostream

I know how to convert a character array containing numbers to an integer using iostream:

```
char[] ar = "1234";
int num;
ar >> num;
```

but how would I convert the last four characters of that array to an int?

```
char[] ar = "sl34nfoe11intk1234";
int num;
????;
```

Is there a way to point to an element in the array and start streaming from there?
Ideally I would start streaming from max array size - 4.

Comment: Are you sure `ar >> num` is valid C++ code? Seems like you forgot the stringstream.

Comment: `char[] ar` is not valid C++ either.

Comment: @Christian, man, you can simply tell him he is wrong. :) He must be a beginner, who doesnt know operations on strings too..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char* p = ar + strlen(ar) - 4;
```

Now `p` points to the `'1'` of `"1234"`, and you can feed `p` into the stream.

Answer (score 2):

```
char ar[] = "abc1234";
std::istringstream ss(ar + 3);
int n = 0;
ss >> n;
```

Better yet, use `std::string`:

```
std::string ar("abc1234");
std::istringstream ss(ar.substr(ar.size() - 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
char[] ar = "sl34nfoe11intk1234";
int num;
(ar + strlen(ar) - 4) >> num;
```

Comment: I assumed that his first example was working. (Using some implicit declaration, since he knew how to...) My point as others also has stated: increase the pointer to the forth last char.